# Passing arguments to variable function from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a python flow in which I store a selected function in a variable - and I want to call the selected function using this variable and arguments passed from a dictionary.

Let's say I have the following functions:

```
def func1(param1,param2,param3):
   ...

def func2(param1):
   ...

def func3(param2,param3):
   ...
```

And in my code I first select the function to use:

```
if condition1:
   f=func1
elif condition2:
   f=func2
elif condition3:
   f=func3
```

Now I would like to use this function. Let's suppose I have a dictionary that contains all the parameters for just in case:
`d={'param1':param1_value,'param2':param2_value,'param3':param3_value}`

I know it is possible to pass the parameters to func1 with `func1(**d)`, however, I would like to pass the same dictionary for func2 & func3. In short, I would like to call `f(**d)` - but for func2 & func3 the signature is lacking some of the arguments. If I would try this as is, python will result in error: "TypeError: func2() takes exactly 1 arguments (3 given)"

I know I can make the signature of the 3 functions to be the same and force it to contain all of the 3 arguments (but to not use it) - but this looks ugly, and the IDE warns me of unused argument in this case.

Do you know of more elegant way to achieve the same? For example, as string format handle this case:

```
d={'name':'my name','location':1,'index':3}
print('my name is {name} and my location is {location}'.format(**d))
```

The above code result in:
`my name is my name and my location is 1`
Even that I provide it with additional argument. Can I do the same in my own functions? Can I do this with relatively simple function signatures?

Comment: You can use `**kwargs` in `func2` to collect the undesired args.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm pretty sure that this will mess the order of the other arguments.

Comment: @DeepSpace, kwargs have no inherent order when specified as kwargs.

Comment: @StephenRauch In 3.7 (or will in 3.8?) it does

Comment: Hi @Roee you can actually pass the same dictionary to all functions, Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

`**d` is called [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) which match the exact arguments provided in the function with the keys of the dictionary, and if the dictionary has extra arguments, you get the exception `TypeError: func2() takes exactly 1 arguments (3 given)`, as you can see in a simple example below

```
In [39]: def func(a,b): 
    ...:     pass 
    ...:      

In [40]: d = {'a':1,'b':2}                                                                                                                                
#All arguments passed and matched against parameters
In [41]: func(**d)                                                                                                                                        

In [42]: d = {'a':1}                                                                                                                                      

#An argument b is missing
In [43]: func(**d)                                                                                                                                        

TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

In [44]: d = {'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}                                                                                                                         
#An extra argument c is passed
In [45]: func(**d)                                                                                                                                        

TypeError: func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```

A better approach is to pass the dictionary itself by doing `funcX(d)`, and extract the params from within the function

```
def func1(dct):
    #Extract known params from the dictionary
    param1 = dct.get('param1')
    param2 = dct.get('param2')
    param3 = dct.get('param3')
    print(param1, param2, param3)

def func2(dct):
    # Extract known params from the dictionary
    param1 = dct.get('param1')
    print(param1)

def func3(dct):
    # Extract known params from the dictionary
    param2 = dct.get('param2')
    param3 = dct.get('param3')
    print(param2, param3)

d={'param1':'param1_value','param2':'param2_value','param3':'param3_value'}

#Pass the same dictionary to all functions
func1(d)
func2(d)
func3(d)
```

The output will be

```
param1_value param2_value param3_value
param1_value
param2_value param3_value
```

Comment: Be warned of `KeyError`, maybe use `.get`? But anyway OP might as well use `**kwargs` but they were reluctant to use it in this case (and I'm as well. As a reader, a function signature with only `dct` or `**kwargs` tells me nothing about the arguments this function is expecting)

Comment: Good idea, fixed @DeepSpace :) Please check if it looks good now and consider upvoting if it looks good :)